# how can use Q library in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

i want use promise in my nodejs project for run function and codes after each other ,
it is my code for test Q libaray :

```
var Q = require('q'); 
    Q(firstFunction)
    .then(function(err){
    fcall(firstFunction);
}).then(console.log('30000'));

function firstFunction(){
    return console.log("in first function");
}

function secondFunction(){
    console.log("in second function");
}
```

but it just run console.log('30000') ... i dont know how to start using Q library..
can u explain node js promise or Q library with examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to clarify [how to use](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) Q.
In your case it could be:

```
var Q = require('q'); 

Q.fcall(firstFunction)
.then(secondFunction)
.done(doneFunction);

function firstFunction(){
    return console.log("in first function");
}

function secondFunction(){
    console.log("in second function");
}

function doneFunction(){
    console.log("all done");
}
```